# Use a php included file as message content in a swiftmail message

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am trying to use an included file in my PHP script as content in a `swiftmail` message.  I want to do something as follows, but it's not working:

Main file:

```
$html = include 'testcontent.php';
$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
```

testcontent.php looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is it not working? What is the Error?

Comment: Are you confusing `include()` with `file_get_contents()` ?
See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: I found a solution.  Since I have php code in the 'included' file, I used the following.  I realize that I could also use file_get_contents (..thanks Dave S) under certain circumstances.  

      ob_start();
   include "testcontent.php";
   $myvar = ob_get_clean();
   $html = $myvar;
            $message = new Swift_Message($subject);
            $message->setFrom($from);
            $message->setBody($html, 'text/html');

This is working great!